# Azure ADDS o365 same Domain

Tags: azure, domain, subdomain

HI iam pretty new to Azure and wanted to implement Azure ADDS for ldap authentification for example wpa2 enterprise and vpn.

Our setup :

We are completly on O365 so nothing on premise our standard domain for email is our own mycompany.com

Now i folowed the microsoft tutorial to setup Azure adds and used the same domain we use in our O365 mycompany.com
I bought a certificate and enabled secure ldap
But if i generate a new user/ reset a password for an existing user in o365 the user is not synced
Or iam i just blind where can i review the users which are already synced

Is that even possible or do i need a subdomain like aads.mycompany.com or cant i ad a subdomain in o365

Will the users even sync to the aadds with the same domain.

I will be greatfull for advice

Answer (score 0):

Users that are already in AAD/O365 are synced to the AADDC Users OU. They cannot be moved out of that OU and cannot be managed from AAD DS, they must be managed from AAD.